# "AmazonGlacierReadOnlyAccess" is not available in Permissions Policy list.. why?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-glacier

I am trying to add new permission to user.

Permission Policy : "AmazonGlacierReadOnlyAccess"

However "AmazonGlacierReadOnlyAccess" is not available when i searched through permissions list.

Only "AmazonGlacierFullAccess" is available.

seems like simple thing.. am i missing something here?!!

Please let me know why it is not available. is it renamed to something else now?

[image]

Comment: Can you double check or try again by refreshing the page? AmazonGlacierReadOnlyAccess is available and visible. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonglacier/latest/dev/access-control-identity-based.html#access-policy-examples-aws-managed

Comment: logged out and logged in again.. Refreshed and checked.. Still its displaying just "AmazonGlacierFullAccess".

Comment: Can someone check from their aws account n verify this?